# How do I install Apache Jena/Java on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, database, jena

total database and Java noob here. Need to start learning how to use Jena (I will probably spend a long time reading the official documentation since It looks decent) but I don't know how to actually set it up, since I don't know a thing about Java or Databases. How do I set it up so I can start to study?